# Making field required based on user input on other input field?

Tags: visualforce, apexinputfield

```
    <td><apex:inputField value="{!child.batchObj.Asked_Qty__c}"/></td>

    <td><apex:inputfield value="{!child.batchObj.Quantity__c}"  required="{!child.batchObj.Asked_Qty__c=0}" style="width:110px"/></td>
```

When inputfield  "`Asked_Qty__c`" was empty .then "`Quantity__c`" was not required .

When inputfield  "`Asked_Qty__c`" was not empty then "`Quantity__c`" was  required

I want to do this asked quantity was entered by salesforce user

Based on input it should take required or not required.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Teja, You can do this by creating a validation rule that if Asked_Qty__c != Null && Quantity__c == null, then throw the error.

Comment: I have to include many fields so i prefer any other process not validation rule

Comment: What about using the .addError as described in this blog here... http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/04/field-level-error-messages-with.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use apex:actionsupport tag and a boolean variable for this. It should look like this

//controller

```
public boolean isRequired {get; set;}

--constructor method--
  isRequired = false;

public void isItRequired(){
  if(check if required){
    isRequired = true;
  }else{
    isRequired = false;
  }
}
```

//vf page

```
<apex:outputPanel id="mypanel">
 <td><apex:inputField value="{!child.batchObj.Asked_Qty__c}">
         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action={!isItRequired}" reRender="mypanel"></apex:actionSupport>
     </apex:inputField>
</td>

<td><apex:inputfield value="{!child.batchObj.Quantity__c}"  required="{!isRequired}" style="width:110px"/></td>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: As far as I've seen, if you toggle this on, then off, the `required` attribute never becomes false again. Once `required`, always `required`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below line:

```
<td><apex:inputfield value="{!child.batchObj.Quantity__c}"  required="{!if(child.batchObj.Asked_Qty__c != NULL,true,false)}" style="width:110px"/></td>
```

Comment: it may work at the first time but  not work if the user update the field because no rerender